# Rインストールの不具合

Tags: r

El capitanでRをインストールし直した。
CRANのミラーサイトに日本のリストが出ず、Chinaを選びました。
installはできたようですが、libraryを実行しません。何を修正すればいいでしょうか。

```
> install.packages("rafalib")
 --- このセッションで使うために、CRAN のミラーサイトを選んでください --- 
 URL 'https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2/rafalib_1.0.0.tgz' を試しています 
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 39769 bytes (38 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 38 KB

 ダウンロードされたパッケージは、以下にあります 
    /var/folders/h1/ggcx_9t93jj_sl7pqjfnrz1c0000gn/T//RtmppBFupd/downloaded_packages 
> library(rafalib)
>
```

Answer (score 0):

`rafalib/README.md` によると、

```
# installation

install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("ririzarr/rafalib")
```

だそうです。

※ `install.packages("devtools")` でかなり時間がかかります。